# Question about Disk Partitioning

Tags: rhel, partition, lvm, disk, fdisk

I'm new to Linux environment and trying to get some clarification on the Disk partitioning.
I've installed new RHEL 8 vmware workstation initially with 20GB Disk and later expanded with additional 20GB. My goal is to create Volume groups & logical volume for later use. I did created a extended partition via fdisk as below,

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 40 GiB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0e287c88

Device         Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *        2048   616447   614400  300M 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p2        616448  4810751  4194304    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/nvme0n1p3       4810752 41943039 37132288 17.7G 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p4      41943040 62914559 20971520   10G  5 Extended
```

However, when I do a `lsblk` it shows the Size as 1K!? Tried rebooting the VM but no luck. Looks like Im doing something wrong or my understood the setup wrongly.

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1     259:0    0   40G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  300M  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 17.7G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0    1K  0 part
```

Can someone point to how to get the 10GB under `nvme0n1p4`? Also, why the disk is getting auto partitioned when I add any new disk in VM?

Comment: If you're already working in a VM, don't bother with partitioning disks -- just make separate disks for each different 'partition' you want to use. Much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Extended partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition) can't be used directly it's just a "container" for logical partitions. It's actually a clever hack to overcome the 4 partition limit in MBR. Your `nvme0n1p4` is a 10 GiB extended partition, but `lsblk` shows it as `1 KiB` because that is its "real size" -- it doesn't take any space on the disk except the `1 KiB` metadata and has "10 GiB of free space" for logical partitions. If you goal is to add a new LVM setup, simply add a new logical partition using `fdisk /dev/nvme0n1` (you can also use `parted`), and use `vgcreate /dev/nvme0n1p5 <vg_name>` (the new logical partition will be `nvme0n1p5`) to create a new volume group on it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So I tried to use both parted / fdisk to create logical partition under the /dev/nvme0n1p4 but no luck,[root@localhost ~]# parted /dev/nvme0n1p4 
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/nvme0n1p4
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: NVMe Device (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1p4: 1024B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags

Comment: (parted) mkpart                                                           
Partition type?  primary/extended?                                        
Partition type?  primary/extended? extended                               
Start? 1GiB
Error: The location 1GiB is outside of the device /dev/nvme0n1p4.

Comment: You need to add the partition to `nvme0n1` -- the disk, not the partition. So `fdisk /dev/nvme0n1` and then `n` for new partition.

Comment: Ah! Got it.. thank you! Also, I was trying to set the Start & End value as 1GiB and 2 GiB instead of the actual partitions start value. After putting the start value as  21.5GiB  and End value as 23.5GiB I can get the lvm now!

Comment: Device         Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *        2048   616447   614400  300M 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p2        616448  4810751  4194304    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/nvme0n1p3       4810752 41943039 37132288 17.7G 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p4      41943040 62914559 20971520   10G  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      45088768 49283071  4194304    2G 83 Linux